# std::regex c++ *.txt

Tags: c++, regex

Which regex should i use to match "123.txt" or "456.txt"
I've tried to std::regex reg("*.txt"), but that's don't worked

Comment: `*.txt` is a [*globbing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern, not a regular expression. There are thousands of tutorials about regular expressions all over the Internet, use your favorite search engine and you will find help quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```cpp
std::regex reg("\\d+\\.txt");
```

- `\d` is to select one digit
- `\d+` is to select a number composed of one or more digits
- `\.` is to select a simple dot (it must be escaped because it's a special symbol in regular expressions)

The `\` is doubled because they must be escaped in a regular C++ string.

Use https://regex101.com/ to try your regular expressions.

Comment: You can use "raw string literals" (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to make that much easier to read. With them, you don't have to escape the backslashes by doubling them.

Comment: I'd recommend raw string literals to avoid all the escape characters when dealing with regex. `std::regex reg(R"(\d+\.txt)");`

Comment: The question is: does he want `R"(\d+\.txt)"` or `R"(\d{3}\.txt)"`, or even `R"(.*\.txt)"`. His question isn't really clear in this regard (although his gobbing pattern would suggest the last.